# reading Named Pipe issue

Tags: c, linux, macos, pipe

I have this code C:

```
#define BUFSIZE 256

int main ( int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fdIn;
    int fdOut;


    if( argc != 3)
    {
        perror("Erro argument");
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (fdIn = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY ) )<0)
    {
        perror("Errr pipe input");
        exit(1);
    }

    if( (fdOut = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY ) )<0)
    {
        perror("Errr pipe output");
        exit(1);
    }

    int c = 2;
    while(c--)
    {
        char var1[BUFSIZE];
        char var2[BUFSIZE];
        char string[100];

        memset(var1, 0, sizeof(var1));
        memset(var2, 0, sizeof(var2));
        memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));


        if( readLine(fdIn, var1, sizeof(var1)) == 0)
        {
            printf("exit1\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        printf("%s\n",var1);
        if( readLine(fdIn, var2, sizeof(var2)) == 0)
        {
            printf("exit2\n");
            exit(0);
        }

        removeNewLine(var1);
        removeNewLine(var2);

        if( atoi(var2) != 0){
            if( atoi(var1) == 0  || (atoi(var1) % atoi(var2)) == 0 )
                sprintf(string,"ok\n");
            else
                sprintf(string,"no\n");

        }

        printf("%s", string);
        writeLine(fdOut, string, strlen(string));
    }
    close(fdOut);
    close(fdIn);
    exit(0);

}
```

Functions used in the code:

```
int readLine( int fd, char* str, int bufferSize)
        {
            return readToDel(fd, '\n', str, bufferSize);
        }

int readToDel( int fd, char delimiter, char* str, int bufferSize)
        {
            int n;
            int byteLetti =0;
            int index=0;

            do /* Read characters until NULL or end-of-input */
            {

                if( (n = read (fd, str+index, 1)) < 0)
                {
                    perror("Errore: lettura dal file descriptor fallita\n");
                    exit(1);
                }
                byteLetti+=n;


            }
            while (n > 0 && *(str+index++) != delimiter && index < bufferSize);


            return byteLetti; /* Return false if end-of-input */
        }
void removeNewLine( char *s )
    {
        removeDel(s, "\r\n");
    }
void removeDel( char *s, char *del)
    {
        s[strcspn ( s, del )] = '\0';
    }
```

I have 2 pipes one for input and other for output. I write on input pipe , using `echo "4\n2\n" > i` (by terminal) the string `"4\n2\n"` and by two readline( the 2 if in the while cycle) I  should read the "4" and then by second readline the "2". This because the `Readline` function splits by '\n'; but when end first if in the while cycle prints `var1` (should contain only `"4"` ) , but it prints `4\n2\n` and I don't understand why.
What do I wrong?

Comment: Use `echo -e "4\n2\n" > i` to send three lines (4, 2, empty) to the file `i`.  As it is, you write one line containing 6 characters and a newline.  Or use `(echo 4; echo 2) > i`.  You can debug by using `echo "4\n2\n"` to see what's written to the file.

Comment: sorry but adding '\n' after each component why readline function doesn't separate component of line?

Comment: Because, if you look at the output, you have a backslash and a letter n in the input to the file, and not a newline.  Granted, that's only what I get on Mac OS X 10.10.5 with Bash 3.2.57, and you might be getting different output on your machine, but that's at least a starting point.  From what you describe, you're seeing the backslash and letter n in the output; that's because it is what's in the input.

Comment: Run `echo "4\n2\n" | od -a` to make sure that `echo "4\n2\n"` is actually producing what you think it is. Most versions of `echo` require a specific flag in order to translate escape sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\n` is not actually a newline character. It's an escape sequence which, ***in some circumstances***, is interpreted and causes the interpreter to substitute a newline character. The C compiler does this interpretation and substitution in string and character literals, so your compiled program actually contains the newline character.

The shell and its `echo` built-in command do not necessarily do this interpretation. The `bash` that ships with OS X does not interpret such escape sequences by default. You can make it do that by passing the `-e` option. Note that `/bin/echo` or the built-in `echo` commands of other shells may not support that option.

So, you throught you were providing the input character stream `4`, newline, `2`, newline, newline to your program. What you were actually providing was `4`, `\`, `n`, `2`, `\`, `n`, newline.